# Short messages widget

Tags: plugins, widgets, plugin-recommendation

i'm looking for a widget that can show short news messages in the sidebar sorted by date (sticky's would be nice too) and manageble in the backend. I don't want to create posts because these messages are max 200 characters and don't need a dedicated page. Is there something like this? My english is giving me problems finding it, or maby it just doesn't excist?

PV

Answer (score 2):

If I were to approach this, I would create a custom post type to create and manage the posts, then loop through the custom post type to show the news messages. But if you don't want to create posts to manage this, that option might not work for you.

Comment: Absolutely +1 for using a Custom Post Type for this.